# How to get the number for processing status in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to make a shortcode to show the number of processing status order in woocommerce.

I found a code that shows the number of processing and I tried to make a shortcode.
But, this doesn't work.

`function get_count_for_processing( $status ){
global $wpdb;

```
// We add 'wc-' prefix when is missing from order staus
$status = 'wc-' . str_replace('wc-', '', $status);

return $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT count(ID)  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_status LIKE '$status' AND `post_type` LIKE 'shop_order'
");
// Display "processing" orders count
```

echo get_count_for_processing( "processing" );
}
add_shortcode('get_count_processing', 'get_count_for_processing');`

This is my second try, but this doens't work at all.
`function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
global $product;

```
// Is a WC product
if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    // Set the orders statuses (without wc-)
    $statuses = array( 'completed' );

    // Call function
    $total_sales = get_product_total_sales_by_order_status( $product->get_id(), $statuses );

    // Display result
    if ( $total_sales >= 1 ) {
        echo sprintf( __( 'Total sales: %d', 'woocommerce' ), $total_sales );
    } else {
        echo __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

}
add_shortcode('test123123', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary');`

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of processing orders in the store using the below function and the shortcode `[count_for_processing]`.

```
add_shortcode('get_count_processing', 'count_for_processing');

function count_for_processing() {
    $args = array(
        'status' => array('wc-processing'),
        'return' => 'ids',
        'limit' => -1,
        'customer_id' => get_current_user_id()
    );
    $processing_order = wc_get_orders($args);
    echo "Number of processing order = " . count($processing_order);
}
```

Comment: Hello. It is working well. However, it is showing the total number of all accounts. I need to get the count only for the current user. Could you plz fix this?